# Compare two strings like url in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have two strings:

```
http://porter.com/request/.*
```

and

```
http://porter.com/request/tokenId
```

I want to check if first parts: `http://porter.com/request` are the same in both and check if `tokenId` is not null, because in some cases it could be only `http://porter.com/request/`. 
I use something like that:

```
override fun validate(pair: Pair<URI, URI>): Boolean {
        val uri = pair.first.path.split("/").dropLast(1).filter { it.isNotBlank() }.joinToString("")
        val uriIntent = pair.second.path.split("/").dropLast(1).filter { it.isNotBlank() }.joinToString("")

        val asd = pair.second.path.split("/").filter { it.isNotBlank() }.last().isNotBlank()

        return uri == uriIntent && asd
    }
```

but this is not working for last case:  `http://porter.com/request/`
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final String regex = "(http://porter.com/request/).+";

/**
 * Below code will return false
 * since, URL doesn't have last path
 */
final String yourUrl = "http://porter.com/request/.*";
final boolean valid = yourUrl.matches(regex)

/**
 * Same (will return false), as ex. above
 */

final String yourUrl = "http://porter.com/request/*";
final boolean valid = yourUrl.matches(regex)

/**
 * This will return true. Link is Ok.
 */

final String yourUrl = "http://porter.com/request/tokenId";
final boolean valid = yourUrl.matches(regex)
```